# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE table SET TypeId = ' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I need to update a table with values passed as parameters from a desktop application. But every time I try to run the query I just get this error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UPDATE
>                           table
>                       SET 
>                           TypeId = ' to data type int.

I tried to isolate the problem by reducing the code to a minimum, and below is the shortest snippet of my actual code and still the problem occurs. I figure its most likely a syntax problem, but after browsing similar issues for a while now, I still can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
DECLARE @typeId int = 175;
DECLARE @item varchar(20)= 'ABC123'
DECLARE @SQLScript varchar(5000);

SET @SQLScript =   'UPDATE
                        table
                    SET 
                        TypeId = ' + @typeId + '
                    WHERE item = ''' + @item + '''
                   '
Print(@SQLScript);
```

What I would expect to come out as a result from the `Print(@SQLScript)` is
the query:

```
UPDATE
    table
SET
    TypeId = 175
WHERE
    item = 'ABC123'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert `@typeID` to a string in order to concatenate it:

```
DECLARE @typeId int = 175;
DECLARE @item varchar(20)= 'ABC123'
DECLARE @SQLScript varchar(5000);

SET @SQLScript = 'UPDATE
                      table
                  SET 
                      TypeId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(128),@typeId) + '
                  WHERE item = ''' + @item + '''
                  '
PRINT(@SQLScript);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve my problem. if my TypeId field is an int, will it still be assigned as an integer?

Comment: @SeanMathew Yes you converting it to a string to use as dynamic SQL, but when you look at your final update string, its a number if that makes sense. i.e. in the dynamic sql you have `TypeId = 175` which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I understand the concept well now!

Comment: @SeanMathew do look as SeanLange's answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using dynamic sql here at all? This should be a simple parameterized query. The code you posted is vulnerable to sql injection. http://bobby-tables.com/

```
DECLARE @typeId int = 175;
DECLARE @item varchar(20)= 'ABC123'

UPDATE
    table
SET 
    TypeId = @typeId
WHERE item = @item
```

Answer (score 1):

You need convert `@typeId` to `VARCHAR`

```
SET @SQLScript =   'UPDATE
                        table
                    SET 
                        TypeId = ' + CAST(@typeId AS VARCHAR(10)) + '
                    WHERE item = ''' + @item + '''
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to use the dynamic SQL here since you can simply do

```
DECLARE @TypeId INT = 175,
        @Item VARCHAR(20) = 'ABC123';

UPDATE T
SET TypeId = @TypeId
WHERE Item = @Item;
```

but if you really need to use a dynamic SQL, then do it the right way

```
DECLARE @TypeId INT = 175,
        @Item VARCHAR(45) = 'ABC123';
        
EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE T SET TypeId = @TypeId WHERE Item = @Item',
                   N'@TypeId INT, @Item VARCHAR(45)',
                   @TypeId,
                   @Item;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8d27d99ec39dfcd87647605a1462ea1) to see how it's working.